# is jquery .find always useful?

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div id="MyDiv">

  <div class="Class1">
    <div class="SClass1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Class2"></div>

</div>
```

Is there any difference between

```
$('#MyDiv').find('.SClass1').show();
```

and

```
$('#MyDiv .SClass1').show();
```

Comment: No, they are equivalent.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context might help with your understanding

Comment: @frenchie - Not that it matters anymore because you've accepted your answer, but you should at least read my answer, as it may be useful for you to know. Happy coding =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you case, using `find()` is pretty senseless (except for readability - but anyone will have another opinion on that). i only use `find()` in cases where it's really needed, like:

```
$('#MyDiv').show().find('.SClass1').css(...);
```

where something has to be done with the parent-element first and something else with one or more of its children.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context states that:

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

Which means

```
$('#MyDiv .SClass1').show();
```

Is only one step away from jQuery internally making it

```
$('#MyDiv').find('.SClass1').show();
```

[View this jsPerf test case to see the differences in speed](http://jsperf.com/test-jquery-find-speed/3)

---

As @Dominic mentioned in the comments, in his [jQuery Anti-Patterns for Performance & Compression presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/paul.irish/perfcompression), Paul Irish states:

> Selector Optimization
>
> Of course, descending from an #id is best

```
// #id-based selector 
var arms = $('#container div.robotarm');

// hyper-optimized #id case first, then find: 
var arms = $('#container').find('div.robotarm');
```

Comment: No. Read the quote again: it says it would be the same as doing `$('.SClass1', $('#MyDiv)).show();` - having the selector as one string is a different thing (but gives the same result).

Comment: Is it no longer the case that the first one is faster/more optimised?
I'm a little unclear of the nitty gritty, but I thought writing your selector with the id first then using find() either skips jQuery's selector engine Sizzle, or makes it more efficient.

My belief is based in Paul Irish's jQuery performance video: http://paulirish.com/2009/perf/ (slide 30)

Comment: @oezi - Equivalent in execution, but not always in speed. See my updated answer where I added a link to a jsPerf that shows just that.

Comment: I think this is overoptimizing for speed. Since you're doing it only once, I'd leave it in the most readable way var arms = $('#container div.robotarm'); 1 minute of developer time is more expensive than 1 ms of user time IMO.

Comment: @frenchie - Click on over to slide 31 of that presentation, it's Paul Irish's opinion that `find()` IS more readable, and I agree.

Comment: @frenchie - Sorry, I meant slide 21.  It's more about context, but still applies. `$('.reply_form', $(this).closest('.comment')).hide();` is less readable than `$(this).closest('.comment').find('.reply_form').hide();`. You are entitled to your opinion though.  I was just answering your question as to is there a difference. The answer is yes, in speed. For the simple applications, it may not ever matter, but in complex deep searches, it definitely would.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially there is no difference. But `find()` is useful if you use it with scoped variables and `this`.

For example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.action').click( function() {
        $(this).find('p').text("hello world");
    });
});
```

Which sets all `p` within anything which has a class named `action` to "hello world".

Answer (score 2):

They are both equivalent. The first one will be slightly slower, since you're doing two queries. The difference in speed is probably not noticable.

You can use `find` in cases when you're creating a plugin / component that gets it's container in the constructor and than you use it as the root of your searches with `find` to make sure that you don't get any elements outside your container.